# JQuery slider set value on create

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

```
$("#slider1").slider({
    min: 1940,
    max: 2013,
    values: [1990, 2013],
    range: true,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        var val = ui.values;
        $('#from1').text(val[0]);
        $('#to1').text(val[1]);
        $('#i_from1').val(val[0]);
        $('#i_to1').val(val[1]);
    },
    create: function (event, ui) {
        alert(ui.values);
    }
});
```

when i make alert, i get undefined value, why is that?, i need to set those values to some html elements on create

Comment: After having a look at the [**documentation**](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/), it looks like the object `ui` has the properties `value` and `values`, but not `val`. Also, if you use a "multi slider", the question is whether `value` is even populated since you have multiple ones.

Comment: i've tried ui.values but is also undefined

Comment: Ok, substituting the `alert` with `console.dir(ui)` shows that the object has no properties. Then the parameter description in the documentation makes sense as well (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-create), it does not list any properties (I thought it might have been a mistake). So the answer is: You cannot access the values inside the `create` event handler this way. Since you set the initial values explicitly (`values: [1990, 2013]`) you don't have to retrieve them dynamically anyway. You *know* that the values are going to be `1990` and `2013`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately in `create` handler, `ui` parameter doesn't have `value` property. You can use this instead:

```
create: function (event, ui) {
    alert($(this).slider("values"));
}
```